# Making a command line, if statements not working

Tags: java, shell, loops

I want to make a command line, just to run basic commands. So far, I've made it so that people can tell the program their name. When I don't enter a name, however, it treats it as if I did. Here is my class:

```
public static void main(String args[])
        throws IOException
{
    int a = 1;

    do
    {
        System.out.print("$$: ");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String wtt = null; // wtt = what they typed!
        wtt = br.readLine();

        if(wtt == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Why wont you tell me your name!");
        }
        else
        {

            System.out.println("Thanks for the name, " + wtt);
        }

    }
    while(a == 1);
}
```

Here is the output

> $$: well
>
> Thanks for the name, well
>
> $$: hole
>
> Thanks for the name, hole
>
> $$:
>
> Thanks for the name,

Why does it not work?

Comment: You are probably getting empty string but you are only testing against null.

Comment: As an aside, if you have to put a comment explaining why you named your variable the way you did, you may want to change the variable name to something more meaningful and readable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
if (wtt == null || wtt.trim().length() == 0)
```

Answer (score 7):

Calling [`readLine()` on a `BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) will only return `null` on end of input.  Here, the input hasn't ended, you've just entered an empty line, so `""` (the empty string) is the result.

You will need to end the input stream, usually with Ctrl-C.  Then you'll get `"Why wont you tell me your name!"`.  But then you'll need to break out of your infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
wtt.length()==0
```

instead of checking for null

Comment: (Actually probably better to do both; with checking for `null` coming first)

Comment: Instead of reinventhing the wheel, use Apache Commons Lang [`StringUtils#isEmpty`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 2):

It's because although you set the string to `null` at first, you are then setting it to `br.readLine()` which will have a line to read even though the user didn't type anything before hitting enter, so it will set the string to an empty string.

You should also (or instead) compare your string to `""` (an empty string) to see if they entered anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare `wtt` to `""` as well to make sure the line isn't empty.

`if (wtt == null) {`

becomes

`if (wtt == null && !!("".equals(wtt))) {`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing wtt to null, compare it to empty string:

```
if ("".equals(wtt))
{
    System.out.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**readLine** method doesn't give you end of line characters (e.g. \n, \r). So, you cannot expect the loop to exit when you press just enter without entering anything. You can use **read** method instead to read characters and determine if there was a new line character or use **Scanner** class which seems to me better suitable in your situation.